# Java Clone object using GSON

Tags: java, clone

I have to clone an object multiple times. My object is non serializable. I am using the following function

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static  T cloneThroughJson(T t) {
   Gson gson = new Gson();
   String json = gson.toJson(t);
   return (T) gson.fromJson(json, t.getClass());
}
// ...
Object cloned = cloneThroughJson(someObject);
```

I found that this is returning every time reference to the same object. e.g

Let's say I first call it for `cloneThroughJson(x)`
it returns `Y`
I again call it in the same function `cloneThroughJson(x)`. And it again returns `Y`.

Do you know how to clone non serializable object in java using deep cloning?

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve]? How do you know it returns the same instance?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that it is a known issue. Your method will **ONLY** work if the copied object has a default no-argument constructor. In order to achieve what you want - you need to create an instance creator.

*From [documentation](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Writing-an-Instance-Creator):*

> While deserializing an Object, Gson needs to create a default instance of the class
>   Well-behaved  classes that are meant for serialization and deserialization should have a no-argument constructor
>   Doesn't matter whether public or private
>   Typically, Instance Creators are needed when you are dealing with a library class that does NOT define a no-argument constructor
>
> Instance Creator Example
>
> ```
> private class MoneyInstanceCreator implements InstanceCreator<Money> {
>   public Money createInstance(Type type) {
>     return new Money("1000000", CurrencyCode.USD);
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> Type could be of a corresponding generic type
>
> - Very useful to invoke constructors which need specific generic type information
> - For example, if the Id class stores the class for which the Id is being created.

Comment: My Class has no argument constructor.